# magento get the phtml file in email template with passing variable from email template to phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, phtml

I am trying to get the phtml file data in email template as well as passing variable from email template to phtml file as like below code. but am not getting the data from phtml file

In email template

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='reorder/related_products.phtml' quick=$emailTemplateVariables.customer_name }}
```

In phtml file:

```
 print_r($block->getData('quick'));
 print_r($this->getQuick());
 echo get_class($this->getQuick());
```

Comment: are you sending email from frontend or admin?

Comment: Sending email from cron job

Comment: your `related_products.phtml` file is located in `base/template`?

Comment: yes, in base/template/reorder/related_products.phtml

Comment: @Satti, template is working but can't pass the variable

Comment: kindly share the code where you  set variable for template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45640/discussion-between-phani-babu-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 0):

in phtml file just write below code and it will work

`echo $this->quick`

I have try in my local and it works .

Answer (score 0):

try with `$customer_name`

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='reorder/related_products.phtml' quick= $customer_name }}
```