# How to validate link in text area

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, contact-us

I used a contact form in my site. If anyone mention any link in message box, it should come as a text on my mail because currently i am receiving the link on my mail.[image: Check this image]
In this image i am getting link in comment section but i want to get this link as a text on the mail.

so how can we validate it.

Comment: Please solve out this problem

Comment: Can you post your email template code

Comment: yeah sure... wait

Comment: Name:  {{var data.name}}
Email:  {{var data.email}}
Subject:  {{var data.subject}}

Comment: {{var data.comment}}

Comment: so u don't want www.google.com as link

Comment: yes i don't want  www.google.com  as a link on my email...

Comment: it should come as a text on the mail

Comment: inorder to do this you will have to override this template and will have to filter content from the comment box

Comment: which template... email template..??

Comment: yes email template..

Comment: ok tell me what i have to do or what code i have to put in the template

Comment: write custom phtml file for email template and mention template handler in transactionalemails

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137213/magento-get-the-phtml-file-in-email-template-with-passing-variable-from-email-te

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57823/how-can-i-include-customized-phtml-file-in-email-template

Comment: sorry dude... as i told you that i am beginner in magento... so i don't have much knowledge about it. Will you please  describe me in your answer... please

Comment: i have never wrote one for contact form.. you will have to go through similar answers.. it will be bit complicated

Comment: ok if you ever get stuck .. feel free to ping me..

Comment: sure...........